# A simple Unobtrusive JavaScript example

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
var el = document.getElementById('btn');
e1.onclick=function()
{
//
    alert('hello');
};
  </script>
  <button type="button" id="btn" >Log-in</button>
```

I am simply testing how unobstrusive javaScript works with a simple button onclick() event but when i click on the `Log-in` button nothing happens alert box doesn appears

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script appears before the button.

It runs before the button is added to the DOM.

`document.getElementById('btn')` doesn't find the button because the button doesn't exist then.

---

Move the script after the button or put it in a function and call that function after the button exists (e.g. from the window's load event).

---

Also, don't rename your variables in the middle of your code. A lower case L and the numeral 1 aren't interchangeable.

Comment: On line 2 you create a variable called `el` (eee el), on line 3 you try to use a variable called `e1` (eee one).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you try to attach the handler before the element exists. `<script>` tags are executed immediately and so the browser hasn't created the button element at that time.

A solution would be to wrap it in `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('btn');
    e1.onclick=function()
    {
    //
        alert('hello');
    };
};
```

Alternatively you can use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event. This differs from `onload` because it doesn't wait for images and CSS to be loaded. It isn't supported by IE8 or lower though:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("ready to attach events");
});
```

Comment: did but nothing seems to be working .It's still the same

Comment: Look at Quentin's comment about the variable name, you use an L then a 1. `el` is not the same as `e1` is it?

Answer (score 0):

yes as said by above 2 answers you can wrap your code in window.onload else you can write a function and call it onclick event of button as shown below

```
function myfunction() {
  alert('Hello');
  };

<input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="Click Me!" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wf8yJ/13/